# cancelling a function with an external event in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where we are progressively showing higher and higher quality images to a user as they download.

The logic looks like this:

3 Image formats : low quality (5-8kb), large (60-80kb), highres (150-250kb).

1. Check if large or high res photo is cached if so simply initially show cached version and FINISH.
2. If not load low quality image and display to the user straight away.
3. precache large image and change img.src once it has loaded.
4. Check users window size if it exceeds a certain threshhold, precache highres image and change img.src on load.

Everything works beautifully.

However during the high res download if a user clicks to go to the next image, everything will of course get screwed up since we have set an event to occur onload when the previous highres image has loaded.

Essentially the onload event is occurring after the user has already clicked to go onto the next image, meaning that the NEW image is getting replaced with the old one.

What I need to do is be able to cancel the function whenever a user changes to the next photo.

The function looks something like this:

```
(function(index){
        $(highresimage).imagesLoaded(function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        self.cache.image = $(highresimage).appendTo(self.cache.imagewrap);
                        self.cache.photos[index]['highresloaded'] = true;
                        setTimeout(function(){
                        self.cache.imagewrap.children('img').first().remove();
                        self.cache.image.css({
                            'left':'',
                            'position':'relative'
                        });
                        },10);
                    },200);
        });
})(index);
```

So I need to be able to programmatically cancel the `$(highresimage).imagesLoaded(function(){});`

What would be the best way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Please note in my example we are actually cloning the image, changing the src, adding it to the dom, leaving a few ms then removing the old image.  This is down to a bug in Firefox which causes flashing when changing the src of high resolution images.  As horrible as it is, removing the ugly timeouts makes the experience far worse for the user in Firefox.  They are there for a reason. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you save the `setTimeout` in a variable, you can use `clearTimeout` to cancel it. In theory, the loading of the images should be aborted.

```
var timeout = setTimeout(do_something, 1000); // create

clearTimeout(timeout); // cancel
```

After looking at [the source code of `imagesLoaded()`](https://gist.github.com/268257), I can't find anything that allows you to cancel that function too which is a bit of a bummer :(

Comment: Of course, how silly of me.  Due to the scope I would need to do something along the lines of self.cache.timeout = setTiimeout(); then cancel it within my click handler.  Makes perfect sense.  How embarrassing that it didn't occur to me. I've clearly not been sleeping enough lately.  Thanks Tim. :)

Answer (score 0):

For a given image, you need to keep track of the latest image that you are waiting for.  Then, when other images that you used to be waiting for finish loading, you can see if the one that finished loading is still what you're waiting for or not.  If not, you just ignore the fact that it finished loading.  If so, you replace the current image with the one you're waiting for.

Your current code is pretty messy (multiple timers) and the use of some plug-in that we aren't familiar with so I don't actually understand how you're timing things or moving to the next image.  But, somewhere you need to keep state for what you want the next image to be and just check to see if an image that finished loading is actually that image or not.  This will keep you from ever putting the wrong image into place.

P.S.  I don't understand why you have two short timeouts in your code.  No timeouts should be needed.  You should be able to start an image loading and then act when it finishes loading with no timeouts.

Comment: You're right we 'should', but as mentioned in my Edit there is a Firefox bug which prevents this when dealing with very high res images.  With the code above, the timing is not an issue whatsoever. Those timeouts are to resolve the Firefox bug and are indeed horrible.  I would much rather simply replace the img.src but this does not work correctly in any firefox version since about 8 (when the bug was introduced) causing flashes with high res images. : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=705826

Comment: @gordyr - I've written an HTML5 slideshow and I stopped ever changing `.src` because I ran into problems.  I create a new object with the new image in it and replace the old object with the new one.  Never had a problem that way.  Never needed work-around timers.

Comment: Have you tried with images in excess of 3000x3000px?  Thats about where I ran into problems.  I know its an ugly hack but I genuinely haven't found anything else that would solve the problem under all conditions on all browsers.   Creating a new Image() object is exactly what I'm doing. Simply replacing in the dom as you suggested was my first solution which although it solved the flashing problem, messed with the vertical/horizontal centering of the image. We have to manipulate the incoming image first unfortunately.

Comment: To be fair I should mention that the 200ms timer is actually nothing to do with the bug.  It is because we are performing an animated transition upon entry which we need to ensure is complete before replacing the image.  We cant use ontransitionend as the image is not gauranteed to be loaded before the event handler is set.  It's actually only the 10ms timer that resolves the issue for me.  I would have explained in more detail but didn't feel it relevant to the question.  Cheers for your help anyway.